# Convert an EAV table to JSON update query

Tags: json, postgresql, entity-attribute-value

I have a simple EAV table, that I want to convert to JSON/B and insert it into a column that I will add to the entity table.

This is meant to be used as a migration query.

My EAV :

Record ( id, ... )
RecInfos ( recordid, key, value )

For earch entry in the record table, it will create a json representation of each key / value that is can be found in the RecInfos table, and this will be send as an update on the Record table.

I am using postgresql 10.3

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I was searching for :

```
update
    record r
set
    infos = (
                select
                        json_agg(json_build_object('name',i.name,'value',i.value))
                from
                        recinfos i
                where
                        i.rec_id = r.id
            )
```